# C: What is the advantage of struct casting to extract data from array?

Tags: c

For the sample code below, both method 1 and 2 can extract data from the array. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both methods? Method 1 looks cleaner but must deal with endianness carefully. What else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t data[] = {0x8A, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t hex2:4;
    uint8_t hex1:4;
    uint16_t num1;
    uint16_t num2;
} RandomStruct;
#pragma pack()

int main()
{
    // Method 1
    RandomStruct *struct1 = (RandomStruct *)data;
    printf("%X\n", struct1->hex1);
    printf("%X\n", struct1->hex2);
    printf("%X\n", struct1->num1);
    printf("%X\n", struct1->num2);
    
    // Method 2
    uint8_t hex1 = data[0] >> 4;
    uint8_t hex2 = data[0] & 0x0F;
    uint16_t num1 = data[1] | (data[2] << 8);
    uint16_t num2 = data[3] | (data[4] << 8);
    printf("%X\n", hex1);
    printf("%X\n", hex2);
    printf("%X\n", num1);
    printf("%X\n", num2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to read about strict aliasing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: Also note that packed structs isn't a standard requirement.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, strict aliasing doesn't come into this, as there's no modification happening through the aliased pointers, only reading.

Comment: @TobySpeight: The aliasing rules of the C standard apply to all access, both reading and writing.

Comment: BItfields are implementation defined.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

Problem 1:  `struct1->hex1`, `struct1->hext2`, `struct->num1`, and `struct1->num2` access the memory of `data`, which has effective type `uint8_t` (which is likely a character type), but they access that memory with a structure type. The behavior of this is undefined because it does not conform to the aliasing rules in C 20186 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: …

(There is a complication here in that the aliasing rules allow “an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members,” but I would not expect the nominal use of `uint8_t` in declaring the bit-field members satisfy that.)

This problem might be fixed by changing `RandomStruct *struct1 = (RandomStruct *)data;` to `RandomStruct struct1;`, using `memcpy(&struct1, data, sizeof struct1);` and changing the subsequent `struct1->` occurrences to `struct1.`.

Problem 2: The C standard does not specify the order in which `hex2` and `hex1` are located in the storage unit used to hold them, per C 2018 6.7.2.1 11:

> … The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined…

Note that the order of allocation of bit-fields is not determined by the endianness of the C implementation. Regardless of whether a C implementation puts low-significance bytes of integer types earlier in memory or later in memory, it may place the first bit-field of a structure in the low bits of the storage unit or in the high bits of the storage unit.

This cannot be fixed portably in C (that is, using only strictly conforming code); you must ensure the members are declared in the necessary order for each C implementation you use.

Problem 3: The two bit-fields of the structure do not necessarily occupy just one byte. C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 says:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field…

This is a separate issue from packing the structure, as the storage unit used for bit-fields would be considered as bytes used for the bit-fields, not padding bytes that are eliminated by packing.

This cannot be fixed portably in C but a violation of the desired layout could be detected with `_Static_assert(sizeof (RandomStruct) == 5, "Error, expected just five bytes in RandomStruct.");`.

### Method 2

Problem 1: `data[1] | (data[2] << 8)` is not guaranteed to work in every C implementation because `data[2]` will be promoted to `int`, and the C standard allows `int` to be 16 bits. If the high bit of `data[2]` is set, then `data[2] << 8` would produce a result greater than or equal to 32,768, which is not representable in a 16-bit `int`. Then overflow occurs, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 6.5.7 4:

> … If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

This could be fixed by casting `data[2]` to `uint16_t` and similarly for `data[4]`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! For the problem 1 in method 1, I understand that writing to alias may lead to unexpected behavior as the compiler optimizes away some loading instruction in the next access. However, I do not understand what the potential problem is if I am just reading via the alias as the sample code. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Sam: Suppose we have a routine `foo` that can see the external definition of `data` as `uint8_t data[] = {…};` and is also passed a pointer to a `RandomStruct`: `void foo(RandomStruct *p) { printf("%d\n", p->hex2); data[0] = -1; printf("%d\n", p->hex2); }`. The C standard allows the compiler to reason here that `p` either does not point to `data` because its type does not conform to the aliasing rules or that it does and the behavior is not defined…

Comment: … In either case, this means the compiler is allowed to generate code that loads the value to be printed for `p->hex2`, then writes to `data[0]`, then uses the already loaded value for `p->hex2` without reloading it to account for the write to `data[0]`. So a compiler could generate that code, and the second `printf` of `p->hex2` would use the old value, not the updated value.

Comment: Let say there is no `data[0] = -1;` in foo routine, does it cause any issue when I simply read the value?